# Ideal inductor in DC circuit

Tags: inductor

If a ideal inductor of inductance L is connected to dc voltage say,V. How does the current change across it?
I tried writing kirchoff's law

\$ V = L \cdot \dfrac{di}{dt} \$

I got

\$ i (t) = i(at \text{ } t=0) + \dfrac{V \cdot t}{L} \$

is my try correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct providing V is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current-voltage relationship for an inductor is: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

The above relationship tells you that current rises linearly when you apply a fixed voltage to the inductor. More generally, the formula can be solved for current by integrating both sides: -

$$i = \dfrac{1}{L}\int{v\: dt}$$

And, for a linearly rising voltage (for instance) with \$v = V_{S}\cdot t\$,

$$i = \dfrac{V_{S}}{L}\int{t\: dt} = \dfrac{V_{S}}{2L}t^2$$

So, if your DC voltage source is fixed at some value, you would use the top formula to calculate how current changes linearly with time. If your DC voltage source is (for example) rising in amplitude, use the last formula. There are of course many other examples where the DC voltage source is changing differently to those above so, this answer is just an example of some possibilities.

Comment: Why did you take current at t=0 to be zero.

Comment: That’s a good question. It was a deliberate choice because I wasn’t aware of your math skills.

Answer (score 0):

From V = L di/dt

di/dt = V/L

So the current change at a constant rate of V/L.

This change is linear.

di = V/L * dt

Take antiderivative(Integral) on both sides

i = V/L * t

this equation tells you what is the value of current at any time.

Comment: You have assumed i=0 at t=0, which is reasonable in this case but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

So for an ideal inductor you have the equation correct for its “ohms law”. 
But let me explain it further. Consider DC source (like a battery) has been connected to an ideal inductor for a long time, say 1 second at least. At DC conditions, the inductor appears like a short circuit because an inductor is simply a coil of wire. Voltage across a short is zero but current would be ideally infinite. In reality it would be some fairly large value like 1 ampere.

Now let’s consider what happens when you actually connect the DC source to the inductor for the first time. Consider battery of voltage V connected to inductor but with some resistance in series (either wire resistance, inductor resistance or just a plain resistor is added). Also imagine a switch connected between the circuit and battery.

When the switch is open, there is no current nor voltage across inductor or across resistor.

At the moment the switch is closed, say at time t=0,  you may write Kirchhoff voltage law equation as VL + VR = Vu(t) where u(t) represents a step input. Since VL= L(di/dt). Now if you plug that in you have a differential equation. Solving that equation would result in a equation for inductor current shown below.

I=V/R( 1-e^(-Rt/L))u(t) 
Or simply

I=V/R( 1-e^(-Rt/L)) for t=>0

VL can be found by using equation VL=L(di/dt).

Now if there is an initial inductor current:

Still apply KVL. And obtain

VL + VR = Vu(t)

But when you solve it, the initial condition isn’t i(0)=0 but rather 
i(0)=I_o. When solving that differential equation using that initial condition you’ll obtain a solution of the form

i=V/R + (I_o - V/R)e^(-Rt/L)

Comment: Ohm's Law does not apply to ideal inductors. Ohm's Law applies only to ideal resistors.

Comment: True that the actual ohms law works for linear resistors. That why I called it “Ohms law”, ie not a real ohms law. Really just mean the voltage current relationship for an inductor. But if you look at it in frequency domain, it likes exactly like ohms law but with impedance.